# Form is not submitting php and html

Tags: php, html

everyone..

trying to submit a form.. and form and php code is in the same file index.php

```
if(isset($_POST['post_form'])) {
    echo "ISSET";

    $post_sender=$id;
    $post_reciever=$id2;
    $post_cont=$_POST['news_text'];
    $post_cont=htmlentities($post_cont);
    $post_cont=mysql_real_escape_string($post_cont);

    $post_sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall_posts (from, to, content, date) VALUES ('$post_sender','$post_reciever','$post_cont',now())") or die(mysql_error());

    }else{
        echo "NOT SET";
    }
```

html form

```
<form  method='POST' action='index.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='news_form' name='post_form' >
<textarea id='news_text' name='news_text' >type here..........</textarea>

<input type='submit' id='wall_post_btn' name='wall_post_btn' value='submit'>

</form>
```

where is my  mistake..???

**there is no mistake in the code..the file itself is corrupted..just made a test in a new PHP file...works just fine...thanks guys..**

Comment: What is the problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: I dont believe that the form itself wil actually send POST data. Does it work if you make a reference to one ofthe text elements? `if(isset($_POST['news_text'])){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is You are checking the name of the form present in the `$_POST`, which is never present...

What You should test is the name of the submit button, e.g.:

```
if(isset($_POST['wall_post_btn'])) {
```

Next You could use one line for sanitizing the input:

```
$post_cont= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['news_text']));
```

And last one: start using PDO with prepared statements or at least `mysqli_*` functions as `mysql_*` ones are deprecated now...

Comment: still new to php...strated with classics..
i know that i have to move to PDO...thanks

Answer (score 2):

`post_form` is the name of form. You must check for the submit button, `wall_post_btn`.

```
if(isset($_POST['wall_post_btn'])) {
  // entire code here
}
```

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for polishing my answer. But will all due respect, i would like to tell you that he/she has specified post_form as the name of the form.

Comment: Sorry about that. I missed that in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

$_POST['wall_post_btn']. the name of the submit, not the form

Answer (score 0):

You should not use mysql as it has been depreciated. look into mysqli or PDO

This:

```
"INSERT INTO wall_posts (from, to, content, date) VALUES ('$post_sender','$post_reciever','$post_cont',now())"
```

should be:

```
"INSERT INTO wall_posts (from, to, content, date) VALUES ('".$post_sender."','".$post_reciever."','".$post_cont."',now())"
```

Comment: No, it **shouldn't**, it **may**... There is nothing wrong when using `"Hello mr. $name."` and there is no need to do `"Hello mr. ".$name`... If he used apostrophes `'`, then he would have to split the string this way: `'Hello mr.'.$name` to make it work...

Comment: The life long struggle of Variable interpolation (VS) concatenations. All will be good until the day that you need $name not to be a variable. There are always 10 different ways to get the same result, some just better written than others.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You need to connect to your mysql server to use mysql_real_...
2. mysql_real_... is deprecated and is being removed from php

Take a look here for alternatives:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Maybe he has a valid connection before that `if` statement. Anyway, this is not the real problem why it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code its working fine

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
   echo "ISSET";
    $post_sender=$id;
    $post_reciever=$id2;
    $post_cont=$_POST['news_text'];
    $post_cont=htmlentities($post_cont);
    $post_cont=mysql_real_escape_string($post_cont);

    $post_sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO wall_posts (from, to, content, date) VALUES ('$post_sender','$post_reciever','$post_cont',now())") or die(mysql_error());

    }else{
        echo "NOT SET";
    }
?>
<form  method='post' action='index.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='news_form' name='post_form' >
<textarea id='news_text' name='news_text' >type here..........</textarea>

<input type='submit' id='wall_post_btn' name='wall_post_btn' value='submit'>

</form>
```